# Classpath invalid flag - Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javac

I am using `javac` to compile a file called `Rengine.jar`.

I tried:

```
javac –classpath ./REngine.jar
javac –cp ./REngine.jar
javac ./REngine.jar
javac –classpath REngine.jar
```

And here are the errors that I got:

---

```
javac: invalid flag: –classpath
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

---

```
javac: invalid flag: –cp
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

---

```
javac: invalid flag: ./REngine.jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

---

```
javac: invalid flag: –classpath
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

I am not familiar with Java at all and I could not find an answer to this problem with a Google search. I precise that I am in the good directory and that I am using Mac OSX. My Java version is 1.8.0_20.
Any advice would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Looks like you have the wrong dash. Try replacing all `–` with a `-`. It looks like you have a unicode EN DASH (U+2013), instead of the ASCII minus sign (hex 2d).

Comment: Thanks! That's indeed a good start, having good dashes... Here is my new error:`javac: no source files
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot compile a `.jar` file. A `.jar` file is a collection of complied `.java` files (`.class` files). You are however able to run a `.jar` file if your manifest file is set up correctly.

The procedure is as follws: 
Compile:

```
javac MyClass.java
```

the above line creates `MyClass.class`

Create JAR with manifest file:

```
jar cfe myJar.jar myClass myClass.class
```

Run JAR:

```
java -jar myJar.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

javac - the Java source compiler, will compile the Java source file `*.java` into JVM bytecode the class file `*.class`

To execute a Java program you need to call a class file with `java YourClass`.

The Jar file is a `Java archive` file. Which contains other files. For example class files. If you want to run a class from within the Jar file there a two way.

**executable Jar**

```
java –jar REngine.jar
```

This depends on the manifest file inside the Jar, which defines the main class which should be executed.

**class inside a Jar file**

```
java –cp REngine.jar package.YourClass
```

This would execute the class `package.YourClass` (assuming the class has a `main` method).

Answer (score 0):

specify the option and source file, try like this:

```
javac -classpath ./lib/* file.java
```

in case you have any problem try specifying which artifact the compiler will use:

```
javac -classpath ./lib/myjar.jar file.java
```