# Why I always received invalid flag error while building .jar

Tags: java, file, jar

Why I always received invalid flag error while I'm building .jar

When I using Build Jar to make a .jar file in java:

```
rm -rf build-jar && mkdir build-jar && javac -d build-jar /Users/user/Desktop/projects/Swings/source/library/* && jar cvf build-jar/window.jar build-jar *
```

I always receive a error:

```
error: invalid flag: /Users/user/Desktop/projects/Swings/source/library/controller
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

If I use path to .class file:

```
rm -rf build-jar && mkdir build-jar && javac -d build-jar /Users/user/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/ca7d24d42ba31de4cfb244fc0f239d07/redhat.java/jdt_ws/swings_12c4bbf0/bin/* && jar cvf build-jar/window.jar build-jar *
```

I also receive an error:

```
zsh: no matches found: Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/ca7d24d42ba31de4cfb244fc0f239d07/redhat.java/jdt_ws/swings_12c4bbf0/bin/*
```

I'm not very familiar with building jar, It make me headache, And I don't know what to do, the other question's solution or solution on internet are all not work for me(like [Classpath invalid flag - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915963/classpath-invalid-flag-java), etc.)

I'm using IDE vscode, and using vscode extension "JAR Builder"

Comment: You aren't getting this 'while building .jar'. You are getting it from the compiler `javac`. Take a look.

Comment: And you need to explain where `/Users/user/Desktop/projects/Swings/source/library/controller` came from. It isn't present in the command line you posted. It is also unclear what you mean by 'use path to .class file'. The directory name `Application Support/` needs to be quoted as it contains a space: possibly you need to quote the entire path in which it appears.

Answer (score 2):

'star' expansion **is a thing your shell does**. When you type `ls *.txt` in your shell, that's *not* what is run. Your shell itself detects that * and will go out and figure out what you really mean. What actually ends up being executed is `ls a.txt b.txt c.txt` - everything that star matches, separated out by spaces.

The same is happening here. Hence, why you get this error: Your shell is executing:

```
javac -d build-jar
 /Users/user/Desktop/projects/Swings/source/library/controller
 /Users/user/Desktop/projects/Swings/source/library/model
 /Users/user/Desktop/projects/Swings/source/library/... and all the other dirs...
```

and here's the clue: **javac does not work like this**. You cannot specify **directories** and expect it to know what to do. You need to list each java file individually, which means you need one heck of a long command line.

There is a reason nobody in the java ecosystem builds apps with the command line. Everybody uses maven or gradle instead. So should you. It'll solve this problem; you just stick your sources in the right location and maven / gradle figure it out from there. Have as many packages as you want.